# Android sms intent filter

Tags: android

I tried this code in my android application for the SMS message but it is not working , the application does not appear in the messaging list. Should I add something to make it work?

```
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

          </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Had you set the permission in the manifest?  android.permission.SEND_SMS permission

Comment: did you tried android.intent.action.SEND (not SENDTO?)

Comment: Please refer my answer in the link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677784/android-register-application-to-send-compose-sms/24068732#24068732

Answer (score 11):

I am providing you a detailed desc to do that in different case(with contacts, text shares etc).

Manifest Entry for you Message Activity

```
<!-- Defines also the app name in the Android menu -->
    <activity
    android:name="it.rainbowbreeze.smsforfree.ui.ActSendSms"
    android:label="@string/common_appName"
    >
    <!-- Sends sms for someone  -->
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Sends text to someone .This will enable any Text Share functionality-->
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now we have made a processIntentData method as shown below to be applied in Message Activity:

```
private void processIntentData(Intent intent)
{
    if (null == intent) return;

    if (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //in the data i'll find the number of the destination
        String destionationNumber = intent.getDataString();
        destionationNumber = URLDecoder.decode(destionationNumber);
        //clear the string
        destionationNumber = destionationNumber.replace("-", "")
            .replace("smsto:", "")
            .replace("sms:", "");
        //and set fields
        mTxtDestination.setText(destionationNumber);

    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()) && "text/plain".equals(intent.getType())) {
        //in the data i'll find the content of the message
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        //clear the string
        mTxtBody.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Use as shown in Message Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    mTxtDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.actsendsms_txtDestination);
    mTxtBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.actsendsms_txtMessage);

    ...

    //executed when the application first runs
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        processIntentData(getIntent());
    }
}
```

The attached snap for results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to send SMS, In your activity manifiest file grand `android.permission.SEND_SMS permission`.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Enter Phone Number:"
   />
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/smsnumber"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="phone"
   />
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Enter Phone SMS Text:"
   />
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/smstext"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/sendsms"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text=" Send SMS "
   />
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/sendsms_intent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text=" Send SMS using Intent.ACTION_SENDTO "
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the Activity class is,AndroidSMS.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidSMS extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       final EditText edittextSmsNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smsnumber);
       final EditText edittextSmsText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smstext);
       Button buttonSendSms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendsms);
       Button buttonSendSms_intent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendsms_intent);

       buttonSendSms.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
    String smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, smsText, null, null);
   }});

       buttonSendSms_intent.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
    String smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);  
    startActivity(intent);
   }});
   }
}
```

Comment: thx for the code but i want solve the manifest and make the application appear like this  http://i.stack.imgur.com/cif2V.png

Comment: @steevoo: you mean, when you click a button or click any one on you application layout you must show which is you mentioned in the link, am i correct?

Comment: without click on button its appear when user want send sms  as whatsapp and skype and those application

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
               

          </intent-filter>
i resolve it in this way