# How to register Broadcast of my app to show as an alternative app

Tags: android

I want to register my App which deal as an optional App. like a user want to send SMS, user goes to contact and select a contact there and get option Call or Message. user select Messege. now i want to show my app as optional with default messaging app,like whats app.I searched a lot but did not  get how to do that. please help me, thanks in advance, i am a new learner.

Comment: Why down vote ? if you don't want to answer then its fine. but please don't try to demotivate.

Comment: somebody voted u done without any reason. So I voted u Up .Bcoz this is not a bad ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an action Intent Filter  .

Something like this

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

</intent-filter>
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847876/android-sms-intent-filter) link you will get some Idea

It works like this

```
         Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.SEND);
        startActivity(intent);
```

It will show you list of all the app which can send sms

Answer (score 0):

Intent Filters registers components as being capable of performing certain actions.
There's plenty of documentation on the subject:

[`<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

[Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

[Manifest-intro - Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#ifs)

(All the above links lead to developer.android pages)

Here's a [bonus link](http://www.slideshare.net/CodeAndroid/android-intent-intent-filter-broadcast-receivers) with slides with a nice example.