# Broadcast Receiver in kotlin

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin

How to use register and create a Broadcast Receiver in Android in Kotlin. Any advice...
In Java, you can create it by declaring it as a Broadcast Receiver. But in Kotlin I am not able to find Broadcast Receiver ...well if it is there then how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean saying 'there is no Broadcast Receiver function'? From Kotlin you can see the same classes which you can see from Java.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

you can do it in  the following way

Create a broadcast receiver object in your activity class

```kotlin
val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {   
        when (intent?.action) {
           BROADCAST_DEFAULT_ALBUM_CHANGED -> handleAlbumChanged()
           BROADCAST_CHANGE_TYPE_CHANGED -> handleChangeTypeChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Register broadcast receiver in onCreate() function of your activity

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                    .registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, IntentFilter(BROADCAST_DEFAULT_ALBUM_CHANGED))
```

unregister it in ondestroy function of your activity

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver)
```

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer you need to register receiver in manifest if it is global broadcast. You don't to do it for local broadcast.

Comment: this could create a memory leak if you Android does not call `onDestroy()` which according to the docs is not guaranteed. onPause / onResume are a better pair

Comment: I agree with @Thalatta, register for your receiver at onResume() and unregister at onPause(), thats the recommended way.

Comment: Wouldn't that stop it from receiving broadcasts in multi window inactive state? Isn't start/stop better?

Answer (score 11):

Anonymous class syntax in Kotlin is like this:

```
val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Really helpful, thanks! But what would you put as the `android:name=""` attribute of `<receiver>` in the manifest?

Answer (score 11):

I've created a [BroadcastReceiver Kotlin extension](https://github.com/TylerMcCraw/android-kotlin-extensions/blob/master/BroadcastReceiver.kt), which you can copy/paste anywhere.
It doesn't do much more than what is already mentioned, but it reduces some of the boilerplate.

Using this extension, you should register/unregister like so:

```
private lateinit var myReceiver: BroadcastReceiver

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    myReceiver = registerReceiver(IntentFilter(BROADCAST_SOMETHING_HAPPENED)) { intent ->
        when (intent?.action) {
            BROADCAST_SOMETHING_HAPPENED -> handleSomethingHappened()
        }
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)
}
```

Comment: what should I use instead of `BROADCAST_SOMETHING_HAPPENED` for SMS recieving

Comment: @StevenElliott that would be answering Hasan's question and not OP's question. If you want to know what intent filter to use for SMS, then google it or post another StackOverflow question. But, there are already other StackOverflow questions on SMS filters, so here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847876/android-sms-intent-filter

Comment: I have a hard time getting this syntax to compile.